# Laravel web app stopped working

Tags: laravel, cron

So I have this unique issue

I have a laravel app that is like alexa and it uses several apis including dmoz, google, json to fetch data about domains.

It has a feature where admin can bulk upload the websites and starts the cron and it keeps updating websites by itself.

Now after reaching approx 1000 websites, the app simply stopped.

I have to use CHOWN -R user /path/to/directory again to get it working.

However after doing this my cron stopped working

I flushed the cronjob and cronb manager tables from the database and delete cron.lock file and then resubmit websites and then start the cron.

Now the cron seems to be working because the rows started to appear in cron manager and cronjob tables and also confirmed by the cron output log, however its not appearing on the website.

Following are my laravel logs.

http://pastebin.com/iYuFmD4p

any idea...???

Comment: Looks like the problem is in CountryController.php:60

Comment: but the app is working fine if i add a website manually.